# Passing a AVLTree between forms

Tags: c#, forms, avl-tree

There is another question that is very similar to mine however after reading it i still cannot get it to work.

I have two forms , MainForm and SecondForm and a few other classes, i need an instance  of my AVLtree and be able to access it through my other forms.

This is what ive done so far

MainForm

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        AddArtist secondForm = new AddArtist();
        public static AVLTree<Artist> treeAVL { get; set; }


        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void butAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            secondForm.Show();

        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

SecondForm

public partial class AddArtist : Form
    {
        String Name1 = "No Name";
        int Members = 0;
        public AVLTreetreeAVL = new AVLTree();

```
    public AddArtist()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeAVL = MainForm.treeAVL;
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void butAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Name1 = tBName.Text;
        Members = (Convert.ToInt32(tBMem.Text));  

        Artist newArtist = new Artist(Name1,Members);
        try
        {
            treeAVL.InsertItem(newArtist);
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Entered", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        tBName.Text = "";
        tBMem.Text = " ";


    }
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated pointing out where im going wrong or how to solve it.

It now compiles however it gives an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object. i hope ive gone about coding this is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

What is the access modifier of AVLTree class? Check if it is private or internal, since your code needs it to be public.

Answer (score 1):

Set `public` on your `parametrized type`

```
public class Artist
{
..

}
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you Nathan

Comment: im having issues with my whole solution now, would i be able to zip it and send it to you, to check out?